# jQuery select2 cannot add click event to custom template

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am attempting to add custom click events to icons I've embedded in a select2 handler. Instead of having the default 'x', I've added three glyphicon icons that I'd like to attach custom click handlers to and take action using the select2 events API from there on out.

It looks like this works if I click on the actual tag, but not on the individual icons as I'd like it to.

My JavaScript looks like the following:

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
        function formatPattern( p )
        {
          if (!p.id) return p.text; 

          var html;
          html = '<div class="action-group">';
          html += '<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>';
          html += '<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></a>';
          html += '<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></a>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '<div class="select-text">' + p.id + '</div>'; 

          return html;
        }

        var tagBox = $( '#tagPicker' );
        tagBox.select2({
          tags: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
          closeOnSelect: false,
          formatResult: formatPattern,
          formatSelection: formatPattern,
          escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
        });

        tagBox = tagBox.data( 'select2' );
        tagBox.selectChoice = (function(fn) {
          return function(data, options) {
              var target;
              console.log(data);
              console.log(options);

              if (options != null) {
                  target = $(options.target);
              }

              if (target && target.hasClass('glyphicon-play')) {
                console.log(" clicked play button " );
              } else {
                  return fn.apply(this, arguments);
              }
          }
        })(tagBox.selectChoice);
    });
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwda44q5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `select2` would only provide the information regarding the element that was clicked since it does not support nested elements ( elements other than li - ul ). However, you can tag the element which was clicked inside the option ( by introducing a `css` class or `data-attribute` - leave that upto you ) and then in your function, find that element as your target.

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
        function formatPattern( p )
        {
          if (!p.id) return p.text; 

          var html;
          html = '<div class="action-group">';
          html += '<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>';
          html += '<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></a>';
          html += '<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></a>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '<div class="select-text">' + p.id + '</div>'; 

          return html;
        }

        var tagBox = $( '#tagPicker' );
        tagBox.select2({
          tags: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
          closeOnSelect: false,
          formatResult: formatPattern,
          formatSelection: formatPattern,
          escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
        });

        // introduce a click handler on the sub elements
        $('.action-group a').on('click',function()
        {
          $('.action-group a').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        })

        tagBox = tagBox.data( 'select2' );
        tagBox.selectChoice = (function(fn) {
          return function(data, options) {

             var target = $(data).find("a.active"); // find the active element
              if (target && target.hasClass('glyphicon-play')) {
                console.log(" clicked play button " );
              } else {
                  return fn.apply(this, arguments);
              }
          }
        })(tagBox.selectChoice);
    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/Lwda44q5/1/

Comment: Looks good, only bug with this is that when a new tag is added, the click event handler doesn't attach to it. I thought `on()` was built for that, but something is off.

Comment: for that you need to declare the handler like : $(document).on("click",".action-group a",function() { });. This would register any dynamic elements created

Comment: definitely tried that - trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: put that logic outside document load

Comment: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwda44q5/2/  I thought about putting it outside `ready()` handler, still seems broke

Comment: Got it sorta working, but the order of events are now incorrect, will post fiddle when I figure it out. `selectChoice` is executing before the `on()` handler

Comment: And that has to do with how events propagate. I'll post a working fiddle shortly. Thanks for all of your help @DinoMyte

Comment: @randombits: Sorry haven't had a chance to look at your previous fiddle with the issue. Glad to know you figured it out :)